# Сокращение метода

Tags: java, строки, if, методы, рефакторинг

Есть кусок кода метода, который вначале проверяет определенные условия

```
public String format(DivisionResult divisionResult) {    
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (divisionResult == null || divisionResult.getDivisor() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    if (divisionResult.getDividend() == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
```

Как с помощью этой строки можно заменить предыдущий код, при этом сократив его?

```
StringBuilder result = checkBaseConditions(dividend, divider)
```

Заменив исходный код на строку с методом, как действовать (работать) дальше? Просто при проверке идет сразу возврат, а дальнейшие расчеты прекращаются.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял, нужен такой метод

```
private StringBuilder checkBaseConditions(int dividend, int divider) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (divider == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    if (dividend == 0) {
        return result.append("0");
    }
    return null;
}


public String format(DivisionResult divisionResult) {
     return checkBaseConditions(divisionResult.getDividend(), divisionResult.getDivisor()).toString();
}
```

Comment: Правильно, а как с этим работать дальше в первом методе? и условие, если divider == 0, return Null !

Comment: @АнтонЛуценко просто возвращать stringBuilder.toString();

Comment: Заменив исходный код на строку с методом, как действовать (работать) дальше? Просто при проверке идет сразу возврат, а дальнейшие расчеты прекращаются.

Comment: @АнтонЛуценко смотри исправление ответа. Судя по тому, что ты написал изначально в вопросе - нужен именно такой подход.

Comment: @АнтонЛуценко в изначально твоем коде, если divider == 0, возвращается пустая строка, а не null. Поэтому я и сделал так